# Incomplete vertical lines in tabular

Tags: tables, multicol, multirow

I've made this table which I am mostly pleased with except that the lines in the last two columns on the top row are not complete. Can I get some help fixing this?[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{tabular}{|c||l|l|l||l|l|l||l||l|}
  \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{Type} 
      & \multicolumn{3}{c||}{Scoring} 
          & \multicolumn{3}{|c||}{Ensemble} 
            & \multirow{2}{*}{Resolution} 
               &\multirow{2}{*}{Storage}  \\          \cline{2-7}
  & LogS & CRPS & IS & MA & QA & Resample \\  \hline
  Bins & x & x & x & x & x & x & J & 100  \\      \hline
  Quantiles & & & x & & x & & J & 10 \\      \hline
  Parametric & x & x & x & x & x & x & \infty & 10  \\   \hline
  Sample & & x & x & & x & x & n draws & 1,000   \\     \hline
  Mixture & x & x & x & x & x & x & \infty & 10 \\      \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate cause of the issue is that you're missing two `&` symbols in the header row following "Resample".

There's a larger issue with your table, though: All those vertical lines and double vertical lines, and most horizontal lines, do absolutely nothing in terms of making the table (a) more readable and (b) more attractive and inviting to look at. Worse, as it is, the table's width exceeds `\textwidth` (using the default page settings for the `article` document class).

I suggest you get rid of all vertical lines and most horizontal lines. I'd also align the numbers in the final column on their (implicit) decimal marker. Finally, I'd use a `tabular*` environment to assure that the table fits inside the textblock.

The following screenshot provides a before-and-after comparison.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow,booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|c||l|l|l||l|l|l||l||l|}
  \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{Type} 
      & \multicolumn{3}{c||}{Scoring} 
          & \multicolumn{3}{|c||}{Ensemble} % this is wrong -- it should be \multicolumn{3}{c||}
            & \multirow{2}{*}{Resolution} 
               &\multirow{2}{*}{Storage}  \\ \cline{2-7}
  & LogS & CRPS & IS & MA & QA & Resample & & \\  \hline
  Bins & x & x & x & x & x & x & J & 100  \\      \hline
  Quantiles & & & x & & x & & J & 10 \\      \hline
  Parametric & x & x & x & x & x & x & $\infty$ & 10  \\   \hline
  Sample & & x & x & & x & x & $n$ draws & 1,000   \\     \hline
  Mixture & x & x & x & x & x & x & $\infty$ & 10 \\      \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip\bigskip

\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\sisetup{group-minimum-digits=4,group-separator={,}}
\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
    l 
    *{7}{c} 
    S[table-format=4.0] }
  \toprule
  Type 
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Scoring} 
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Ensemble} 
  & Resolution
  & {Storage}  \\  
  \cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{5-7}
  & LogS & CRPS & IS & MA & QA & Resample & & \\
  \midrule
  Bins & x & x & x & x & x & x & J & 100  \\ 
  Quantiles & & & x & & x & & J & 10 \\      
  Parametric & x & x & x & x & x & x & $\infty$ & 10  \\
  Sample & & x & x & & x & x & $n$ draws & 1000   \\
  Mixture & x & x & x & x & x & x & $\infty$ & 10 \\      
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```